# reverse_iterator related crashes in Visual C++. Is it legal code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, stl, iterator

I was playing around with some code today, and was very surprised to find out that the following code crashes in Visual C++.  Does it look OK?  gcc prints out 1 when I run the code.  So does Intel.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> sampleSet;
    sampleSet.insert(1);
    sampleSet.insert(2);
    sampleSet.insert(3);
    std::set<int>::iterator normalIt(sampleSet.begin());
    std::set<int>::reverse_iterator reverseIt(sampleSet.rbegin());

    ++normalIt;
    ++reverseIt;

    int test1(*reverseIt); // 2
    assert(*normalIt == *reverseIt); //they're both = 2
    std::set<int>::iterator gonnaDelete((++reverseIt).base()); // gonnaDelete points to 2
    int test2(*reverseIt); // 1
    sampleSet.erase(gonnaDelete);
    int test3(*reverseIt); // 1???   Visual Studio 2010 crashes here.... gcc is fine, but not sure if this is legal
    std::cout << test3 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not legal. According to [lib.associative.reqmts] in C++98, "the erase members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements." Since reverse_iterator is defined something like:

```
template<typename Iter>
class reverse_iterator {
  Iter current;
  Iter tmp;
 public:
  ...
  Iter base() { return current; }
  reference operator*() {
    tmp = current;
    --tmp;
    return *tmp;
  }
};
```

when you erase `gonnaDelete` you also invalidate `reverseIt.current`, so when you subsequently dereference `reverseIt`, you get undefined behavior.

Now, set iterators tend to be simple pointers to nodes, and optimized allocators sometimes leave the memory of a deleted node alone, so the code sometimes happens to do what you expect even after you've invalidated one of them, but it's not at all guaranteed to work. I suspect VC++ has a debugging mode on by default to catch this kind of mistake. To turn on gcc's equivalent mode, try building with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/manual/manual/bk01pt03ch17s03.html

Answer (score 1):

std::vector::erase(i) invalidates any iterators referring to vector elements before the "i"

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xd04bzs.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, this the stripped down version.  My code is actually using a std::multimap, and I meant to use a std::set (instead of vector) as an example.  It still crashes with set.  MSDN Link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h4a3515.aspx)

Comment: I answered the question as written.  If you want to ask a different question, start a different StackOverflow question.